# Segfault generated by glEnableVertexArrayAttrib

Tags: opengl, go, vbo

I'm writing a simple OpenGL program using [go-gl](https://github.com/go-gl/gl). While the program runs fine on most machines, it fails with a segfault when running under Windows on my laptop (it works on Linux though - this is what's odd about it). The culprit is my call to `glEnableVertexArrayAttrib`. I've attached the stack trace and relevant code below.

Partial stack trace:

```
Exception 0xc0000005 0x8 0x0 0x0
PC=0x0
signal arrived during external code execution

github.com/go-gl/gl/v3.3-core/gl._Cfunc_glowEnableVertexArrayAttrib(0x0, 0x1)
    github.com/go-gl/gl/v3.3-core/gl/_obj/_cgo_gotypes.go:4141 +0x41
github.com/go-gl/gl/v3.3-core/gl.EnableVertexArrayAttrib(0x1)
    C:/Users/mpron/go/src/github.com/go-gl/gl/v3.3-core/gl/package.go:5874 +0x3a
github.com/caseif/cubic-go/graphics.prepareVbo(0x1, 0xc0820086e0, 0xc0820a7e70)
    C:/Users/mpron/go/src/github.com/caseif/cubic-go/graphics/block_renderer.go:145 +0x108
```

Relevant code:

```golang
gl.GenVertexArrays(1, &vaoHandle)
gl.BindVertexArray(vaoHandle)
gl.BindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, handle)
gl.BufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, len(*vbo) * 4, gl.Ptr(*vbo), gl.STATIC_DRAW)
gl.EnableVertexArrayAttrib(vaoHandle, positionAttrIndex) // line 145
gl.VertexAttribPointer(positionAttrIndex, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 12, nil)
```

Comment: I don't know anything about go, but `0x0` in stacktrace suggests you don't have this function on target machine. What's GL actual version on target machine? What is a minimum GL version you write your code for?

Comment: Ah, it was a subtle mistake. I was calling `glEnableVertexArrayAttrib` instead of `glEnableVertexAttribArray`. The latter is available since 2.1, the former only since 4.5. Still a bit odd that the Linux driver supports it while the Windows driver doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a subtle mistake in calling `glEnableVertexArrayAttrib`, only available since OpenGL 4.5, instead of `glEnableVertexAttribArray`, which is available since OpenGL 2.1. The former function allows attribute arrays to be toggled on a per-VAO basis, which isn't at all necessary in this context.